# iOS Write Data to file, FILE DOES NOT EXIST

Tags: ios, image, caching, nsdata, writetofile

I'm tryin to write the datas of an Image in the cacheDirectory, like this :

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) else { fatalError("Impossible to read the image") }
try! imageData.write(to: cachedImageURL, options: .atomic)
print(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: cachedImageURL.absoluteString))
```

Where **image** is a working UIImage.
the Print statement always returns False. The file is never written, and any exception is raised due to the "**try!**"

Any idea ?

printing the cachedImageURL, it looks like this

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7B6B72C8-E794-4474-A658-48B66AEA31EC/Library/Caches/79d0e60e-5961-4538-bd9f-28187f4e26d0.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out. The problem come from my print

```
print(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: cachedImageURL.absoluteString))
```

which should be **cachedImageURL.path** insteadOf **cachedImageURL.absoluteString**

```
print(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: cachedImageURL.path))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try below Code for saving Images to Caches Directory

*NOTE : if you are saving more than one, please give different image name for all

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let imageName = "image.jpg" //Need to change if more images want to save

do {
    let cachesDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
    let fileURL = cachesDirectory.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
    let image = your image //Give your image here
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
        try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
        print("Image Saved")
    }
} catch {
       print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: i run same code i'm able to store image in caches directory.